# Unable to saveAs .docx file after modifications

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, com, interop

I'm building a software to modify docx files using Microsoft.Interop.Word. Users can add text, tables and so on.

When trying to SaveAs the document, I get a COM  or a Cast error depending on the code I'm trying to use.

If I try to close the document before saving, I get the following error :

> System.InvalidCastException : 'Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{0002096B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: The requested object does not exist. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80010114).'

If I avoid closing the document, I get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : 'Word cannot save this
>   file because it is already open elsewhere.

This is my simple Save function :

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application _appClass = null;
private Document _doc = null;
private object READONLY = (object)false;
public object M = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

public DocBrowser()
{
    _appClass = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    _doc = _appClass.Documents.Open(ref oldFileName, ref M, ref READONLY,
                                  ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M,
                                  ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M);
    InsertText("test text");
    SaveDocx("temp.docx");
}

public void InsertText(string text)
{
    Paragraph oPara;
    object oStyleName = "Normal";
    oPara = _doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref M);
    oPara.Range.Text = text;
    oPara.Range.set_Style(ref oStyleName);
    oPara.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

    oPara = null;
    oStyleName = null;
}

public void SaveDocx(string newDocPath)
{
    object newFileName = (object)newDocPath;
    object fileType = (object)WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault;

    // Trying to close document first 

    /*if (_doc != null)
    {
        _doc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
    }*/

    _doc.SaveAs(ref newFileName, ref fileType,
        ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M,
        ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M, ref M);
}
```

I really can't manage to save the file, I also tried to saveAs a PDF file without success.

Comment: Weirdly, if I just ```_doc.Save()``` everything is fine so I guess it's something about the ```SaveAs``` function ?

Comment: Did you check `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in your list of references ? **Embed Interop Type** or **Specific Version** ; try to play with them ...

Comment: Is this running in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: @FabriceT I tried to change those properties already, nothing's changing !

Comment: @SimonMourier The document modification is happening in a separate thread indeed, but the "saving" part is coming from a a button. totally synchroneous, do you think it could be the source of the problem ?

Comment: There's unfortunately not enough context. For starters, we have no idea what `_doc` is. A [mcve] would help us help you track this down... But the second error does read like a file lock.

Comment: @CindyMeister I've edited the code with minimal reproducible example. Any idea on why this file lock is here ?

Comment: This is reproducible, with just this code? What about the separate thread mentioned in another comment? Word doesn't "play well" with separate threads... Also, try altering `SaveDocx` to take a `Word.Document` object and pass `_doc` from `DocBrowser`, just to see if that makes a difference. Also try declaring it locally instead of at the class level and test that. I'm currently on a mobile device and it's the end of my day, so I can't test, just make suggestions based on what I'm seeing...

Comment: Try to create and use the same Word object in one unique thread. It can be any thread, but all accesses (creation, method calls, destruction) to a given Word object should happen within the same thread.

Comment: @CindyMeister I can like a full example if you need to. Unfortunately, my all DocBrowser is a class also used to display this document in a webBrowser on the Winform software, so I think what you're saying wouldn't be an option since the doc file must remain open during the editing to avoid opening and closing the document a bunch of time and have to wait for this.

Comment: @SimonMourier has said before, the way the software works would't allow me to operate all of these function in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can't SaveAs on an existing file, just deleting the file if it exists and then SaveAs made everything work, still a strange behavior.

Comment: Technically, this statement is *not* correct. It certainly is possible to use `SaveAs` on an existing file - otherwise it would make no sense to have the method. Developer use it all the time.. The problem must come from how the entire code in the project is handling the COM objects, as intimated in the comments to the question. Office applicatios are STA - they do not support "threading". All actions need to take place in a single thread for the object model to work as designed.

Comment: Still a helpful answer because it showed me that I need to feed it a fresh path from `Path.GetTempFileName()`